# How come the difference between 'View page source' and document.querySelector("html").innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, youtube

I want to extract subtitles from this YouTube page ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35PinDPNPw0&ab_channel=CrashCourse)).
I found *timedtext*, when looking via 'View page source'.

But not when I search via javascript console. It won't find it:

```
document.querySelector("html").innerHTML.match("timedtext")
```

But for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4J1hU7XR3w&ab_channel=LeM%C3%A9dia) other YouTube page, it does actually work both.

How come the difference and how to fix it?

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect us to go sift through the source code from third party sites to help you.

Comment: If you want to extract the subtitles *using this way*, consider instead search for the *script* tag that has the `ytInitialData` variable = that's the one that has the url of the timedtext. Also, in your question, your second link is broken. I can't  tell the difference, but, I assume the javascript code inject the HTML code once the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, Marco! Paste this in your console: ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks

Comment: @WimdenHerder I posted an answer that highlights both comments. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[As I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395716/how-come-the-difference-between-view-page-source-and-document-queryselectorh#comment127893245_72395716)*, if you want to extract the subtitles *using this way*, consider instead search for the script tag that has the `ytInitialData` variable = that's the one that has the url of the timedtext.

I can't tell the difference, but, I assume the javascript code injects the HTML code once the page is loaded.

After pasting the line you share in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395716/how-come-the-difference-between-view-page-source-and-document-queryselectorh#comment127894226_72395716):

```
ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks
```

I got the timedtexts in the available languages. Keep in mind, though, probably not all videos has auto-generated captions - [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrbRMvYOvLg)

In that example, I didn't get the captions, so, I don't think that inspecting the source code of the page works for all videos.

Comment: Great answer. thanks! Some video's just don't have captions :) `ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions` is `undefined` in that case

Comment: I found another video with captions, but still no ytInitialPlayerResponse 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA-LMRFhzaw&ab_channel=jordifieke
in view page source you can find timedtext, but not when you try programmatically with document.querySelector("html").innerHTML

Comment: I fixed by fetching the url again:
```const response = await fetch(document.location.href);
const html = await response.text();```